# prime ng as root angular5

Tags: angular5, primeng

- i am working with project in angular5 , where i have different
  modules for different entities.
- i need to use primeng for component ui ,i installed it properly, test
  with demo angular project with single app module :

i have following module:

app (angular generated , app.module.ts)

user(user.module.ts)

```
1. create user component

2  update user component
```

admin(admin.module.ts)

```
1. create admin component

2 . update user component
```

problem :
when i am working with multiple modules , how to  set up primeng in app.module.ts file ?

i am using primeng button in createuser.component with

```
> <button pButton type="button" label="Click" ></button> <p-button
> label="Click" ></p-button>
```

i got following error

> 'p-button' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'p-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'p-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   (" [ERROR
>   ->]"): ng:///PreMeritModule/AddformComponent.html@1:0

my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

//prime ng needs following modules with browser animation module and froms module

import { PanelModule } from 'primeng/components/panel/panel';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/components/button/button';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { userModule } from './user/user.module';
import { adminModule } from './admin/admin.module';

// Routing Module
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
      userModule,
      adminModule
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    PanelModule,
    ButtonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please provide the modules code. It seems you don't have imported the ButtonModule in your module.

Comment: i tried with PanelModule.forRoot() , its not worked

Comment: i know how to use primeng in single module app , the issue is how to setup is as a root and used in all other modules

Answer (score 0):

Modify this import:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

...to add...

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

...then:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: ...
  ...
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

In full:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

//prime ng needs following modules with browser animation module and froms module

import { PanelModule } from 'primeng/components/panel/panel';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/components/button/button';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { userModule } from './user/user.module';
import { adminModule } from './admin/admin.module';

// Routing Module
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
      userModule,
      adminModule
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    PanelModule,
    ButtonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate this ?

Comment: Elaborated above.

Comment: i have updated code but facing same problem , elaborate mease explain use of "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA"

Comment: I was merely showing what the error message is asking you to do. If that doesn't solve it, I guess the error message is misleading.

Comment: thanks   kshetline.... is there any way to add primeng modules as a root in app.module.ts ??

Comment: i got one solution , when i adding this ng prime components in respected module such as user.module.ts it works ,... but i don't want to repeat  this for every module

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know a way to avoid that.